# Cordova Facebook Connect fail on init

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

The error is:

```
Cordova Facebook Connect fail on init

Something went wrong com.facebook.Session
```

I am using this cordova plugin:

```
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin
```

I also downloaded the latest FacebookSDK

I also added the following to config.xml:

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect" value="org.apache.cordova.facebook.ConnectPlugin" />
```

I also added the "facebooksdk.jar" to the "Referenced Libraries" to my project.

I also changed the facebook id in the Hackbook example:

```
<script>
  // Initialize the Facebook SDK
  document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
      FB.init({
          appId: '433859509993839',
          nativeInterface: CDV.FB,
          useCachedDialogs: false
      });

      FB.getLoginStatus(handleStatusChange);

      authUser();
      updateAuthElements();
  });
```

But when I run the sample "Hackbook" then the error is shown. Please help, maybe just some hints for me.

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me, are you sure your references are good?

Comment: did u get it fixed. I am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

In your config.xml, Add this :

```
<access origin="*" subdomains="true">
```

Also, [refer this.](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin/issues/388)